# Cannot understand why undefined index

Tags: php

I'm still new to php and still experimenting about. I'm getting an undefined index for the variable :

```
$httpreferer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

The entire code of the page is:

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();
$current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$httpreferer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

function loggedin(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Sorry if this is a lame question. I'm still a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there may not be a referrer or it may not be provided

Comment: 'HTTP_REFERER' "This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted. "

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` might not be set in the HTTP request. Test for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] with `isset()` before assigning it.

Comment: So the error could be nothing ?

Comment: this should help .. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php  .. the error is simply saying for that execution, referer isn't there

Comment: NOTICE not ERROR, there is a diffirence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browsers (clients) are free to send any HTTP headers they like. You cannot trust them!

Check whether the client provided one using `isset()`:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  // do something
}
```

Bear in mind that this not tell anything about the data itself. It may be anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the visitor doesn't have a referrer (for various reasons he may not, like directly accessing a page - and not clicking a link on another website, or coming from an HTTPS link), then this variable will not be there.

What you can do is this

```
$httpreferer = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? '' : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

This is a ternary operator.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php