# Getting undefined index error in cURL options

Tags: php, curl, http-referer

I have the following options that I am trying to set for my cURL object:

```
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $targetUrl,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: ' . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'],
    'Referer: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
  ),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
  CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$username:$password"
);
```

And I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_TYPE
>
> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

Am I specifying the wrong name for those options, or are they just not being provided in the header?

Comment: Those values are only available if you're running the script in SAPI mode,e.g. inside a webserver. In command-line/CLI mode, they're not defined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369615/serverhttp-referer-missing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167280/cannot-understand-why-undefined-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. About Content-type you can find a explanation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#110763

And there are a few words also about `HTTP_REFERER`. The main point is:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.